# ObjectDB EntityManager not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, objectdb

I'm working with Tomcat, Eclipse and Maven. I added the ObjectDB to the project (libraries > add external jar).

In Eclipse everything seems to be okay. It does not show any "not found" errors and the autocomplete works. But when I run the project it shows this error message:

```
Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;

viewId=/login.xhtml
location=...
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - javax.persistence.EntityManager
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
```

Is anything wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates that ObjectDB is not in the Tomcat / web application classpath (although it may be in the classpath that is used by the compiler).

Try to add it to the web application classpath (see [this tutorial](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/web/project)) or at the server (Tomcat) level.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and add this to your repositories in maven:

```
<repository>
  <id>objectdb</id>
  <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
  <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
</repository>
```

And add this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
  <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6_02</version>
</dependency>
```